# Jupyter Notebook Code Not Working in Text Editor (MacOS)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Recently, I wrote some code for machine learning (NLP) on Jupyter Notebook. Now, I am trying to incorporate this code into VSCode, so I can run it in a browser using PyScript. However, the terminal says

```
File "/Users/eduardoculloch/Desktop/HTML/test6.py", line 1, in <module>
import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

My code is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import random
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

df=pd.read_csv('Book8.csv', names=['Phrase', 'Anger'])

df_x = df['Phrase']

df_y = df['Anger']

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df_x, df_y, test_size=0.2, random_state=4)

tfidfvectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', stop_words='english')
x_traincv = tfidfvectorizer.fit_transform(x_train.astype('U'))

a = x_traincv.toarray()

x_testcv=tfidfvectorizer.transform(x_test)

x_testcv = x_testcv.toarray()

mnb = MultinomialNB()

b=np.array(y_test)
error_score = 0
b=np.array(y_test)
mnb.fit(x_traincv,y_train)
for i in range(len(x_test)):
    testmessage=x_test.iloc[i]
    predictions = mnb.predict(x_testcv[i].reshape(1,-1))
    error_score = error_score + (predictions-int(b[i]))**2
    print(testmessage + ': ')
    print(predictions)
print(error_score/len(x_test))
```

Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

Comment: VSCode can't find the Python installation that Jupyter is using. Have you told it where to look?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: It appears you have 2 Python installations. That can easily happen without your being aware of it. Your Jupyter installation has `pandas` and `numpy` installed. Vanilla installations don't automatically have these modules: you have to install them. VS code is clearly using an installation that doesn't have them.  So you either have to tell VSCcode to use the installation that does have them, or install `pandas` and`numpy` in the one that doesn't.

Comment: I installed pandas using pip3; still not working (still says ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas').

Comment: Please look at what VSCode tells you about the interpreter it is using. Then compare that with the `pip` log that tells you where it put the modules it installed.